# Setting up a promise in Node Js

Tags: node.js, promise

I am having trouble setting up my promise in my code. This is what I have implemented right now:

```
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            ATVStatement();
            let isdone = true;
            if(isdone){
                resolve();
            }else{
                reject();
            }
        }) 
promise.then(CustomMessage());
```

The problem I am getting is that the I pretty sure that the promise is not working. If anyone could spot the error that I am doing I would greatly appreciate it.

#### EDIT

Here is code for the the two functions being used:

```
function ATVStatement() {           
        request = new Request("select distinct(\"Product Name\") from SPA_Data_Feeds where \"Strategic Priority\" = 'Accelerate to Value (LD)'", 
            function(err, rowCount, rows) 
                {
                    console.log(rowCount + ' row(s) returned');
                }
            );
            
             
         //var result = "";
         var count = 0
         
            
             request.on('row', function(columns) {
                columns.forEach(function(column) {
                    console.log("%s\t", column.value);
                    result+= column.value + "\t\n"; //result is a global variable
                    count++;
                    
                 }); 
                 });
        
        connection.execSql(request);
       }

function CustomMessage(){
       console.log('here')
       var customMessage = new builder.Message(session)
                            .text("### Here is a list of the ATV Compounds:  \n" + "> %s  ", result)
                            .textFormat("markdown")
                            .speak("Here is what I found for \'%s\'.", session.message.text)
                            .textLocale("en-us");
                        session.send(customMessage); }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so now we understand the code a little better (thanks for updating), we need to modify the ATVStatement to return a promise and resolve it when the query is complete.

We change the code above to:

```
let atvPromise = ATVStatement();
atvPromise.then ((result) => {
    CustomMessage();
}).catch ( (err) => {
    console.log('An error occurred: ' + err);
});

function ATVStatement() {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request = new Request("select distinct(\"Product Name\") from SPA_Data_Feeds where \"Strategic Priority\" = 'Accelerate to Value (LD)'", 
            function(err, rowCount, rows) 
                {
                    console.log(rowCount + ' row(s) returned');
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve(rows);
                    }
                }
            );


        var count = 0

        request.on('row', function(columns) {
            columns.forEach(function(column) {
                console.log("%s\t", column.value);
                result+= column.value + "\t\n"; //result is a global variable
                count++;

             }); 
             });

        connection.execSql(request);

    });
}
```

You see, ATVStatement was actually asynchronous.

Comment: I tried running your code but I get the same output, and I also but some console.log() statements to see if its something wrong with the functions but I see that the CustomMessage function still finishes running after the ATVStatement function

Comment: Ok, I see,, ATVStatement returns a promise? Is this correct? If it does then I'll update the code in the answer.

Comment: no the ATVStatement runs some code and the CustomMessage outputs a message from the ATVStatement but I need the ATVStatement function the finish first to get the full messsage

Comment: I can add the code for the two functions to the question if that would help

Comment: I think that would be helpful! I'm sure we can find a solution.

Comment: Thanks @MohammedSaleh, I've updated the answer, I can see why the code wasn't working, if you could update with the changes I've suggested that would be cool.

Comment: Hey thanks for the update, but the problem now is that the CustomMessage never get ran. I even added in a console.log() statement before the call to the CustomMessage function and that doesnt appear as well

Comment: Hmmm, could you update the code in request.on('Done') to  request.on('done', function (rowCount, more, rows) { 
            console.log('Request done: Rowcount: ' + rowCount);
            resolve(rows);
        });       .. and then see if you get the console message Request done?

Comment: I've updated again, and tested! Please try again, thanks!

Comment: Great! This is a common pattern, returning a promise from an asynchronous function